FaceTime video call from unknown
I received a FaceTime video call from redacted@icloud.com , and didn’t answer. (The actual iCloud address seemed legitimate, but unknown to me)
No face was visible. I have recently updated my IOS to 18. It this normal or any software issue?

Sadly, this occasionally happens and isn’t a bug in 18.
